# Unity iOS build on my iMac only creates xcodeproject and on my MBP create xcworkspace along with xcodeproject

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

i have two macs, when i build unity iOS project from MBP after build it generates xcworkspace and xcodeproject. But if i build from iMac only xcode project is built. 
All the settings in unity are same. Why is this happening, any possible reasons ?

Comment: What are the versions of xcode and OS X that you're using on these computers?

Comment: got it. Reason was cocoa-pods. macbook pro had cocoapods installed and i mac didn't